# Unable to obtain element when trying to click Facebook cookie

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium python and trying to accept the cookies in facebook login. I am trying to login into Instagram with my Facebook account. Can you please give a way-out?

By.ID seems to be changing everytime.[image]

```
PATH = r"/Users/u/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'bIiDR').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'KPnG0').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[contains(@title,'Allow essential and optional cookies')]")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Helped with below statement.

```js
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Allow essential and optional cookies")]'))).click()
```